# Is that possible to set ALL Alpha in DirectX running to some value, like 0.75?

Tags: c++, directx, transparent, alpha

I have some transparent items, but NOT every item is acting like an Ice Cube, so I'll be more radical. I want a way to change the "alpha" of EVERYTHING in DirectX, every face...

This can be done ever with some temporary cfg file, or by some 3rd part software.

Comment: DirectX 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11? And not everyone's a 'dude' here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you draw the objects.

Generally, you can set the blend state to use a constant factor. If you use DirectX11, you would set `SrcBlend` to `D3D11_BLEND_BLEND_FACTOR` and `DestBlend` to `D3D11_BLEND_INV_BLEND_FACTOR` or vice versa. The factor can be set with [OMSetBlendState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There are methods to achieve this in other versions of DX as well.